# Quit after printing between two patterns using sed

Tags: sed

I'm using sed to print lines between two word patterns. But I only want to print the first occurrence of both words.

```
pattern1
example1
pattern2
pattern1
example2
pattern2

only the
'pattern1' 
'example1'
```

I'm currently using the following command but it print all the occurrences that match.

```
sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/{/pattern2/!p;}'
```

Is there a way to quit after finding the pattern2?

Comment: You have two patterns.  Then you talk about first occurrence of both words... what words are those?

Comment: @AllanWind As mentioned in the example, I only want to print from the first pattern1 occurrence and until the pattern2 (excluding the pattern2). It should after the printing first between lines

Comment: You use "between" to mean including the first pattern and excluding the 2nd which I thought was unclear.  The answer I provided should be correct based on your clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is:

```
sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/{/pattern2/{q};p}' file
```

Which has the form:

```
sed -n '/PAT1/,/PAT2/{/PAT2/{q};p}'
```

Which breaks down as

- `sed -n '/PAT1/,/PAT2/` - locate the range between `PAT1` and `PAT2` and suppress printing;
- `/PAT2/{q};` - if it matches `PAT2` quit (done);
- `p` - print all lines that fell within `/PAT1/,/PAT2/` before quit was reached.

**Example Use/Output**

With your input in `file`, you would get:

```
$ sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/{/pattern2/{q};p}' file
pattern1
example1
```

Answer (score 1):

Quit if we match the 2nd pattern, otherwise print:

```
sed -n '/pattern1/,$ {/pattern2/q; p}'
```

If `pattern2` is not found it will print from pattern1 to last line.  If you use the range `/pattern1/,/pattern2/` it would print all lines if `pattern2` is not found.  Op didn't specify so both are probably valid answers.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try the following:

```
sed -n '
/pattern1/{     ;# if the pattern matches, execute the block
:l              ;# define a label "l"
p               ;# print the pattern space
n               ;# read the next line
/pattern2/q     ;# if the 2nd pattern matches, exit the script
b l             ;# go to label "l"
}' file
```